# Solr Query: With Sort operation

Tags: sql, asp.net, solr

I have some records which has field named 'Location'.
I am using *solr query* for it. Value of Location is like `Irvin,California,USA`. Now my requirement is records which have location like '*USA*' or '*United States*' should be listed first.

Simple descending order, I can get using

```
'sort=Location Desc'
```

But i want records with value `USA` first.

I know the sql query for it.

```
order by ('Location'='USA') Desc, 'Location' "
```

I want it into solr query. I searched in Google but can't get proper way.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write (and use) your custom function (as a Solr Plugin) for that. See https://dzone.com/articles/how-write-custom-solr